# Problem in processing with 3k+ configuration combinations

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

This line was slow https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php#L146 tentatively it takes about 15 seconds each time when I try to change the configurable options. If I use

`print_r($result)` it is keep on loading with download in progress with 2GB+, so I stopped it.. Any idea to resolve this?